# How to redirect URL with queries to index.html using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have searched all over stack overflow for this answer but could not seem to find anything so I decided to give it a try and post my question.

I have the following Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^clients\/viewClients\/invoice\/\?id=([0-9]+)&invoice=([0-9]+)$ index.html
```

I want it to work in a way such that when a user types

> .../clients/viewClients/invoice/?id=28137&invoice=16884

into the browser, he or she is redirected to index.html

I have tested this rule with a regex tester and the url passes.

I was confused because the following Rewrite rule works:

```
RewriteRule ^clients\/viewClients\/\?id=([0-9]+)$   index.html
```

when the user enters this url:

> ../clients/viewClients/?id=28137

The only difference between these two rules is that the first one has an extra path and an extra parameter in the search query.

I'm hoping someone could clarify this problem for me and provide a solution for the first Rewrite rule

Comment: Are you sure you mean `.html` and not `.php`? An `.html` page is not going to be able to process that querystring.

Comment: I do mean html, I just want the user to be redirected back to the homepage for now, I will not be worrying about the query string on index.html

Comment: @RiggsFolly  It is possible to place php code in any file type. It just needs to be configured correctly.

Comment: @Croises Yes it is! But it is not usual, and if that is what is being done, then it really should be mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None can work because the query string is not part of the RewriteRule test url.

You can rewrite all the queries with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^clients/viewClients/ index.html [NC,L]
```

or for the first only:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .+
RewriteRule ^clients/viewClients/invoice/$ index.html [NC,L]
```